# Flutter: Firebase Storage does not upload file on release mode

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

say I have a raisedbutton that has an `onPressed: ()=> uploadFile(_image.path) // File _image = new File();`
and here's my function.

```
Future<Null> uploadFile(String filepath) async {

final String fileName = '$myImage.jpg';
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(filepath);
final Directory tempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
final File file = File('${tempDir.path}/$fileName');
file.writeAsBytes(bytes.buffer.asInt8List(), mode: FileMode.write);
final StorageReference storageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('justAnImage/$fileName');
final StorageUploadTask task = storageRef.putFile(file);

final Uri downloadUrl = (await task.future).downloadUrl;
path = downloadUrl.toString();
return path;
```

}

It does upload an image to Firebase Storage on debug mode, but on release mode. it gives me an error.
`Cannot open file, path = '/data/local/tmp/myImage123.jpg' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)`

I've already setup my Cloud Storage to allow read and write in security rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it with a package called [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider) and change the following code

Before:

```
final Directory tempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
```

After:

```
final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
```